# What causes eDSPermissionError when running dscl?

Tags: user-account

I'm running Mac OS X 10.14.1 revision 18B75

I created a user using dscl and set its home directory to a wrong path with this command:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/theusername NFSHomeDirectory /the/wrong/path
```

Now I want to fix this.
I tried these commands:

```
sudo dscl . -changei /Users/theusername NFSHomeDirectory 1 /the/right/path
```

and

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/theusername NFSHomeDirectory /the/wrong/path /the/right/path
```

but in both cases I get this:

```
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
```

Why am I getting a permission error even if I'm running as root?
How can I fix the wrong path?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @Monomeeth 10.14.1 revision 18B75. I edited my question to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good question. I honestly have no idea. Does Apple still support using NFS home directories?

The only thing I can think of is to mention that using `sudo` is **not** the same as executing a command with `uid=0`, `gid=0`. Necessarily. Anymore.

And this is particularly applicable within the context of Directory Services, I think (?),  because that's where you Enable Root User these days. So I might try enabling root in Directory Utility, and trying with a proper `su root`?